# Scale-building in SPSS

Tags: spss

I'm using Cronbach's alpha to analyze data in order to build/refine a scale. This is a tedious process in SPSS, since it doesn't automatically optimize the scale, so I'm hoping there is a way to use syntax to speed it up.

So I start with a set of items, set up the OMS control panel to capture the item-total statistics table, and the run the alpha analysis. This pushes the item-total stats into a new dataset. Then I check the alpha value, and use it in syntax to screen out items that have a greater alpha-if-deleted value.

Then I re-run the analysis with only the items passed the screening. And I repeat, until all the items pass the screening. Here is the syntax:

```
* First syntax sets up OMS, and then runs the alpha analysis. 
* In the reliability syntax, I have to manually add the variables and the Scale name.

* OMS.
DATASET DECLARE  alpha_worksheet.
OMS
/SELECT TABLES
/IF COMMANDS=['Reliability'] SUBTYPES=['Item Total Statistics']
/DESTINATION FORMAT=SAV NUMBERED=TableNumber_
OUTFILE='alpha_worksheet' VIEWER=YES.

RELIABILITY 
/VARIABLES=
points_18618 
points_18618 
points_3286 
points_3290 
points_3583 
points_4018 
points_7775 
points_7789 
points_7792 
points_18631 
points_18652 
/SCALE('2017 Fall CRN 4157 Exam 01 v. 1.0') ALL 
/MODEL=ALPHA 
/SUMMARY=TOTAL.

* Second syntax identifies any variables in the OMS dataset that are LTE the alpha value. 
* I have to manually enter the alpha value...

DATASET ACTIVATE alpha_worksheet.
IF  (CronbachsAlphaifItemDeleted <= .694) Keep =1.
EXECUTE.

SORT CASES BY Keep(D).
```

Ideally, instead of having to repeat this process over and over, I'd like syntax that would automate this process.

Hope that makes sense, and if you have a solution thanks in advance (this has been bugging me for years!) Cheers

Comment: It's definitely possible to automate this process. But please post some sample data and your present syntax so we can work from it.

Comment: Added the syntax to the OP, thanks for the suggestion, not sure how to post data but I'll try that next

Comment: the steps would be something like this: (1) add an OMS command to capture the alpha value (2) match the alpha value to your "alpha_worksheet", select only the relevant variable names (3) use `write out` to create a new `reliability` command with the relevant variables (4) create program/macro to loop over this process.

Comment: The scope of this is too big to write as an answer here - you should write a separate question for each step.